# Objective C: Draw(Write) on Touch in a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have this code on my touchesMoved but like the others its not working on UIScrollView

Here it is, on my touchesMoved:

```
touchSwiped = YES;

    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentTouch.y -= 5;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [writeView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 15);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    writeView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    endPoint = currentTouch;

    touchMoved++;

    if (touchMoved == 10) {
        touchMoved = 0;
    }
```

so, i transferred it using Gesture recognizer but still it is not working.

i used the PanGestureRecognizer

here:

```
- (void) writePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)writingRecognizerP {
    switch (writingRecognizerP.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

            [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
            [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

            touchSwiped = YES;

            currentTouch = [writingRecognizerP locationInView:scrollView];
            currentTouch.y -= 5;

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
            [writeView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];

            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 15);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
            writeView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            endPoint = currentTouch;

            touchMoved++;

            if (touchMoved == 10) {
                touchMoved = 0;
            }


            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
            [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            break;

    }

}
```

anyone who has an idea how will i able to write on touch??

it'll be much appreciated! :)

Comment: What is writeView?  And what is its relationship to self in the view hierarchy?

Comment: it is a clear UIImageView, it is where the drawing should appear.

Comment: If you NSLog(@"%@", writeView), is it correctly in the view hierarchy and of the right size?

Comment: 1) Is either method getting called?  2) How are you setting up the gesture recognizer? 3) If so, if you add a             CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1); and then a CGContextFillRect(context, self.view.bounds), do you see any red rectangles?    I'm trying to determine the exact point of failure - this isn't exactly the normal way of drawing updates to a view, but it looks like it still should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should do all your drawing in `-drawRect:`, and when something changes send your view `-setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` message.